# Facebook fan page tab views

Tags: facebook, graph, facebook-fql, apr

I am looking for a way to capture facebook fan page tab views metrics, where i can specify the date range

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an application for you tab and then you will have facebook insights for the app which will give you a lot of statistics about the page views and the users.

Do you already have an application for your tab ? Then you can view your insights at :

```
http://www.facebook.com/insights/?sk=ao_YOUR-APPLICATION-ID
```

Where you replace YOUR-APPLICATION-ID by the real value.

Please comment on this so that I can understand your situation a little bit more ?